# Split a nested list into separate lists and insert them into a treeview

Tags: python, list, tkinter, treeview

I have 2 lists

```
the_nested_list=[[31.753, 68.245, 0.002, 3.791, 50.723], [28.753, 71.245, 0.002, 3.977, 53.169], [27.622, 72.376, 0.002, 4.032, 52.682]]
```

and `a=[a,b,c]`

I want to populate a treeview with 3 rows. in each row, the 1st column should be `a` and `b` and `c`. To get a table looks like this

[image]

How do I achieve this in tkinter?
I have tried `datas = np.append(a,the_nested_list)` and `tree.insert('', tk.END, values=(datas.tolist()))` but it's not correctly displaying the values inside the treeview.

Comment: Create a pandas dataframe, then use 'pandastable' https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/description.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be easier to understand.

```
# Your data
the_nested_list=[[31.753, 68.245, 0.002, 3.791, 50.723],
 [28.753, 71.245, 0.002, 3.977, 53.169],
 [27.622, 72.376, 0.002, 4.032, 52.682]]
rows =['a','b','c']

# adding data to the treeview
for contact,r in zip(the_nested_list,rows):
    tree.insert('', tk.END, values=list(r)+contact)
```